# Load CSS properties of another page on click

Tags: jquery

When someone clicks a link, I'd like three things to happen:

1) Content to fade out, leaving only the background image

2) The background image to fade into the background image of the page behind the hyperlink

3) Once the new background image is loaded, proceed with the hyperlink event, and bring the 
user to the new page (where the new content will fade in).

I think this would give a nice continuity effect, but I'm having trouble fetching url of the background image of a link. I could use .load to change the contents of a , but haven't been able to find a way to do this for a CSS property.

PS: Ignore the {% tags %}: I'm using Django template tags for referencing URLs, and these are working fine (...for now :) )

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
    <head>
        {% block title %}<title>Title Goes Here</title>{% endblock %}
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'css/style.css' %}'>
        <style>
            body{
                background: url("{% block bgImage %} {% static 'images/backgroundimages/Cactus.JPG' %} {% endblock %}");
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
    <script src='{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').css('display', 'none');
            $('body').fadeIn(1000);
            $(".navLink").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();              
                var targetLink = $(this).attr('href');
                ***Do something to get the URL of the background image of the page pointed at by targetLink***

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    {% block nav %}
        <nav>
            <a href='{% url 'home' %}' class='navLink'>Home</a>
            <a href='{% url 'about' %}' class='navLink'>About</a>
            <a href='{% url 'services:services' %}' class='navLink'>Services</a>
            <a href='{% url 'portfolio:portfolio' %}'class='navLink'>Portfolio</a>
            <a href='{% url 'projects:projects' %}' class='navLink'>Projects</a>
            <a href='{% url 'contact' %}' class='navLink'>Contact</a>
        </nav>
    {% endblock %}
        <div id='wrapper'>
           {% block content %}
              Content Goes Here
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you get this to consistently transition smoothly without using AJAX and history.PushState. But just for the heck of it...

First you should put your background-images in the global style.css with classes associated with pages. And add your transitions in the css instead of jQuery.

### CSS

```css
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;       
            transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
       -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
            transition-delay: 1s;
}

.home-page {
    background-image: url(bg-home.jpg);
}

.about-page {
    background-image: url(bg-about.jpg);
}

.content {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
       -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
            transition: opacity 1s linear;
 }

.fade-in {
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

Then use jQuery to add and remove classes to start transitions and and handle navigating pages.

### jQuery

```js
$(function () {
    $body = $("body");
    $content = $(".content");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $content.addClass("fade-in");
    }, 200);

    function onTransitionEnd(href) {
        $content.on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd transitionend',
            function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        $body.on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd transitionend',
            function () {
                window.location = href;
            });
    };

    function pageTransition(toPageLink, toPageClass) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $body.removeClass().addClass(toPageClass);
        $content.removeClass("fade-in");
        onTransitionEnd(toPageLink);
    };

    $(".home-link").on("click", function (event) {     
        pageTransition($(this).attr('href'), 'home-page')
    });

    $(".about-link").on("click", function (event) {
        pageTransition($(this).attr('href'), 'about-page')
    })
});
```

Then the markup for pages would have classes on the body and links.

### HTML

Home page example

```
<body class="home-page">
    <nav>
        <a href="home.html" class="home-link">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html" class="about-link">About</a></nav>
    <div class="content">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

About page example

```
<body class="about-page">
    <nav>
        <a href="home.html" class="home-link">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html" class="about-link">About</a></nav>
    <div class="content">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</body>
```

Otherwise, you can just try this plugin that fetches content using ajax, does transitions, and updates the url: http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/